# search a file using python

Tags: python, search

my problem is when I search a pdf file using python. I search it line by line so suppose I have a line contains:

**"this this this %this"**

so if we put 
**x = "this this this %this"** and I want to count the number of "this" and ignore what proceeds "%" as it is a comment. the code is :

```
if re.search("%",x):
    new_line = x.split()
    for g in new_line:
        if re.search("%",g):
            break
        elif g == "this":
            counter = counter+1
    print (counter)
```

but what if I have the following:

x = "this this this %this %this" the second percentage ends the comment and I want to skip "this" which is between "%" and count the last one

have any one any Idea to do it ?

Comment: If you are opening a PDF file as a text file and attempting to parse out the contents, be aware that PDF files often *do not* store their contents in sequential text strings as it appears on the output.  Parsing raw PDF can be an essentially impossible task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = "this this this %this %this"

data = ' '.join(data.split('%')[::2])

data # => "this this this  this"
```

Comment: thank you very much. could I ask you more question if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
x = re.sub("%[^%]*%?", "", x);
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/tE6rL7

Comment: Than you very much it worked like a magic. please I'm working in a project and I need further help if you don't mind?